# Phoenix Ecto Model Nesting

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework, ecto, elixir

So I am trying to make a content system in phoenix, where there are courses, folders, and lessons, and object is the backbone of everything, so:

Object:

```
has_many :children, Content.Object
belongs_to :parent, Content.Object
```

Course

```
belongs_to :object, Content.Object
```

Folder

```
belongs_to :object, Content.Object
```

This method has a problem, though.
I can't seem to find a way to get the folder from a course. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
iex(1)> course = Content.get_course!(1)
iex(2)> [folderObj | _] = course.object.children
iex(3)> folder = folderObj.item
```

But obviously the item field doesn't exist on object. How would I add this?
(Also I can add more code if it isn't clear, just comment)

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb is: *If you find yourself naming something “Object” you are doing it wrong.*

Even if the code you provided was building what you expect, `course.object.children` would have returned a collection of *both* courses and folders, and there was no way to grab the head of this list and expect it’d be a folder (as you do in the line 2.) Also, we do not have a polymorphism in OOP meaning in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir). `Course` is a `Course`, it cannot be also “somewhat `Object`.”

So you should separately build a tree of the *objects*. For that, your `object` schema looks fine, and the internets are full of examples of how to build a tree.

Besides children, the *object* should have many *courses*, many *folders* and many *lessons*. Then the call to `course.object.folders` (assuming everything is preloaded properly) would result in the collection of *folders* as you wanted.

To get to all the folders, including those belonging to children, you would need to implement the recursive walk through the tree children, the applicable algorithms are beyond the subject here.

Of course, there could be many other ways to impolement the similar functionality, but for what you shared that one seems to be the most robust.